# How to call "SET LOCAL" in PostgreSQL with MyBatis

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

### Background:

- In PostgreSQL, you can set work_mem for current transition with `SET LOCAL work_mem = 32768`.
- I am using MyBatis as O/R mapper, so that I can change SQL without changing the Java source codes.
- If I find performance problems in SQL at software testing phases, I will have to add a call of `SET LOCAL work_mem = 32768` just before the problem SQL.

### Question:

How can I add a call of `SET LOCAL work_mem = 32768` without changing Java code with MyBatis?

Comment: Do you only need that for a single statement or for all statements of that (Postgres) user?

Comment: I want to change `work_mem` only for a single statement that has performance problem. The other (non-problematic) SQL statement should not be affected with this change. It is accceptable the change to `work_mem` affect to the other the non-problematic statement in the same transaction that the problematic SQL belongs to.